# Issue with turning a character into an integer in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer, character

I am having issues with converting character variables into integer variables. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char string[] = "A2";
    char letter = string[0];
    char number = string[1];
    char numbers[] = "12345678";
    char letters[] = "ABCDEFGH";
    int row;
    int column;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(number == numbers[i]){
            row = number;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to convert the variable row into the integer value of the variable number, instead of 2 I get 50. The goal so far is to convert the variable row into the accurate value of the character variable number, which in this case is 2. I'm a little confused as to why the variable row is 50 and not 2. Can any one explain to me why it is not converting accurately?

Comment: `50` is the numeric ASCII value of the character `'2'`. Perhaps you are using the wrong format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: Google 'ascii table'

Comment: It's a common idiom when you want the value of a text digit to do something like `value = digit -'0'`. This will subtract the ASCII value of 0 (48) from the digit character (or whatever the value is if you have a non-ASCII system).

Answer (score 4):

`'2' != 2`. The '2' character, in ASCII, is 50 in decimal (0x32 in hex). See http://www.asciitable.com/

If you're sure they're really numbers you can just use `(numbers[i] - '0')` to get the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

2 in your case is a character, and that character's value is 50 because that's the decimal version of the byte value that represents the character 2 in ASCII.  Remember, c is very low level and characters are essentially the same thing as any other value: a sequence of bytes.  Just like letters are represented as bytes, so are the character representation of their value in our base 10 system.  It might seem that 2 should have been represented with the value 2, but it wasn't.

If you use the `atoi` function, it will look at the string and compute the decimal value represented by the characters in your string.

However, if you're only converting one character to the decimal value it represents , you can take a short cut. subtract the digit from the value of '0'.  Though the digits are not represented by the base 10 value they have for us humans, they *are* ordered sequentially in the ASCII code.  And since in C the characters are simply byte values, the difference between a numeric character 0-9 and 0 is the value of the character.

```
char c = '2'; 
int i = c - '0';
```

If you understand why that would work, you get what I'm saying.